# Breaking my while loop

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, while-loop, break

I have created the basic structure to the program, but I cant seem to exit the loop no matter what I try.

Also I want it to display the information that the user will input; from the keyboard, on to the console once I have exited the loop, but I am not sure as to how to do that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Requirement1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        String name, game, time, points;
        int i = 0;

        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Name");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Players Name: " + name);
        while (i < 100)
        {

        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter a Game Name (If You Are Done type \"quit\")");
        game = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Game: " + game);

        Scanner scan3 = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Score");
        points = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your Score: " + points);

        Scanner scan4= new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter the amount of time Spent Playing in Minutes");
        time = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Time played: " + time);
        }



    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to do to break from the loop? I don't see any such attempts.

Comment: You are doing while(i < 100), where are you incrementing i, so that it will grow each time the loop is running? Btw i dont think that you want your while loop to run until i < 100, you want something like that: while(scan.hasNextLine())

Comment: To add to @SotiriosDelimanolis's comment. the loop would exit when `(i<100)` is false, but `i` is not changing inside the loop at all!

Comment: `(i < 100)`. this is your loop condition. what are you doing to try to make this false?

Comment: Why are you creating so many instances of `Scanner`? And why are you wanting to create instances on each iteration?

Comment: @DrewKennedy create and then not use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I like to use a `for` loop when I know the exact number of times the loop will run. If I don't know how many times the loop will run, then I like to use a `while` loop.

A `for` loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Requirement1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        String name, game, time, points;

        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Name");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Players Name: " + name);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Game Name (If You Are Done type \"quit\")");
            game = scan.nextLine();

            if (game.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Game: " + game);

            Scanner scan3 = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Please Enter Your Score");
            points = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Your Score: " + points);

            Scanner scan4= new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Please Enter the amount of time Spent Playing in Minutes");
            time = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Time played: " + time);
        }
    }
```

A `while` loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Requirement1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        String name, game, time, points;

        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Name");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Players Name: " + name);

        while (true) {

            Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Game Name (If You Are Done type \"quit\")");
            game = scan.nextLine();

            if (game.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Game: " + game);

            Scanner scan3 = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Please Enter Your Score");
            points = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Your Score: " + points);

            Scanner scan4= new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Please Enter the amount of time Spent Playing in Minutes");
            time = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Time played: " + time);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot!

Comment: I have come to face another problem, would it be possible to email you for more help?

Comment: @YakubMiah - it would probably be better to just ask another question on stackoverflow, that way more people could look at it (and perhaps give you a better answer than i could.)

Answer (score 5):

Include an `i++` inside of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

In order to break out of the while loop, you need to either make `i < 100` false, or add an explicit statement to stop the loop (`break`, `return`, `throw` or `System.exit`, depending upon your requirements).

If you want to break the loop when the user enters `"quit"` and execute the code following the loop:

```
System.out.println("Please Enter a Game Name (If You Are Done type \"quit\")");
game = scan.nextLine();
if (game.equals("quit")) {
  break;
}
```

At present, `i` is never changed from 0, so `i < 100` is always true. Also, it is not read otherwise. Unless you need it for some other purpose, you can remove `i` and change the while loop declaration to:

```
while (true) {
  // ...
}
```

This condition obviously can never be false, so you would need an explicit break in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to make use of the `for` loop, and is more correct for your needs:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop being a simple counter, you might want to replace it with a for-loop as it indicates better that the loop does not break because of some operations happening within the loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
    // block running 100 times
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible avoid using do / while in favour of a for loop. If the game loop should end when the user types quit, add a break statement.

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    // get user's game choice from console

    if (game.equals("quit")){
        break;
    }

    // if they didn't type quit ...
}
```